overlap 2 distributions in R
I try to compare normal distribution and log distribution with the same mean and same standard deviation and would like to plot an overlaid histogram, with below snippet:
library(quantmod) # to load required library
x<-getSymbols("AAPL",auto.assign=FALSE)  # to download datam in this case the stock price of Apple (AAPL)
x.logret<-diff(log(x[,6])) # to extract the closing price and calculate the log return values
x.logret<-na.omit(x.logret) # to remove NA value(s)

x.avg=mean(x.logret)# to calculate the mean of the dataset
x.sd=sd(x.logret) # to calculate the standard deviation of the dataset

normal.samples=rnorm(300,x.avg,x.sd)
breakpoints=seq(-0.15,0.15,by=0.01)

hist(normal.samples,
     breaks=breakpoints,
     xlab="",
     main="log return of stock X (blue) vs Normal (gray)")

hist(x.logret,
     breaks=breakpoints,
     add=TRUE,
     col="blue",
     main="")

The first histogram is shown with no issue, however, when the second one is entered there is an error msg (Error in hist.default(x.logret, breaks = breakpoints, add = TRUE, col = "blue",  :
some 'x' not counted; maybe 'breaks' do not span range of 'x'). The setting of break point is from -0.15 to 0.15, which should be enough to span over the dataset. Any ideas on what happens? Thanks and any ideas are appreciated.

You need to plot x.logret$AAPL.Adjusted

x.logret is not a numeric vector as hist() expects
